# Crypt .rar file with Javascript or Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

Hi everyOne i try to crypt (and decrypt) a .rar file with Javascript that working for text but is possible with folders or zip files ( for heavy file ) ??

My code is like this :

```
const fileger = require("fileger")
const file = new fileger.File("./fofo1.rar");

file.encrypt("your-password") // this will encrypt the file
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Encrypt Done")
})

file.decrypt("your-password") // this will decrypt the file   
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("Decrypt Done ")
    })
```

When i try to decrypt i have this fatal error ...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[12424:000001DD0893F130]    15726 ms: Mark-sweep 2131.6 (2165.3) -> 2131.6 (2165.3) MB, 598.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.230, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[12424:000001DD0893F130]    16485 ms: Mark-sweep 2131.6 (2165.3) -> 2131.6 (2134.3) MB, 759.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.140, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

```
0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF6C06FA09D]
```

Security context: 0x02ad921408d1 
1: join [000002AD921555F9](this=0x03f10bad5b11 <JSArray[83776576]>,0x01a062c00731 <String[#0]: >)
2: stringify [0000031F527509B1] [C:\Users\Mangoz'\Desktop\COOODE\crytoTest\node_modules\crypto-js\enc-base64.js:71] [bytecode=0000017CD859A209 offset=332](this=0x031f5274f651 ,0x017cd85be0a1 <Object map = 0000036A38CBEC89...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: Looks like that your encryption function is loading the complete file into memory and you run into "out of memory error". Try to encrypt in chunks.

Comment: i have update the memory with : "node __max_old_space_size=4096" . now that return "decrypt done " but when i try to open the .rar file that give an error : " the headers are corrupt " . What is the problem ?

Comment: _fileger_ seems to be only able to encrypt (UTF8 encoded) text files. Also, CryptoJS is applied internally, without file streaming, using the internal (deprecated and insecure) key derivation function. The ciphertext is Base64 encoded and thus enlarged by about 33%. All in all, for arbitrary binary or large files another library probably needs to be applied, e.g. the _crypto_ module of NodeJS. This allows different streaming strategies, e.g. with pipes, supports various KDFs, and is not limited to text files.